# MySql - How to return only part of a field - remove a certain word if exist in field

Tags: mysql

I have a field that contains a variety of text values that occasionally have a consistent string appended to the end of the field.

Example field values:
Part One
Part Two - New
Part Three - New
Part Four

I need to query that field but strip off the "- New" from the result.

What I need returned:
Part One
Part Two
Part Three
Part Four

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like `select replace('Part One Part Two - New Part Three - New Part Four', '- New','');`

Comment: I don't want to actually replace it in the table. I just need return that cleaned up value so I can use it for a JOIN.

Comment: this query doesnt replace in the table, only the result is cleaned up

Comment: ahh. gotcha. sorry yes, select being used here, not update. Thanks.